# How to fix: "cannot read property" for create voice channel with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, voice

I search to create a bot for creating voice channel by join one specific other voice channel, but I have an error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined"

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember, message) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel


    if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
        var idVoiceChannel = newMember.voiceChannelID
        console.log('Join')
       if (idVoiceChannel === "605468426846800900") { //test
        console.log('test')
        bot.channel.createChannel('General', "voice").then(chan => {
            chan.userLimit("5");
        })
       }else if(idVoiceChannel === "607223548620755073"){
        console.log('testing 2')
       }

    } else if(newUserChannel === undefined){

      // User leaves a voice channel
      console.log('Leave');
    }
  })
```

Comment: Does the error appear on "bot.channel.createChannel" line?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WY8eheLS

here is all of the message error

Comment: Replacing `bot.channel.createChannel` with `message.guild.createChannel` should work.
Also, don't forget to check if your bot has enough permissions!

Comment: message implicated to have a command ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. Try replacing `bot.channel.createChannel` with `newMember.guild.createChannel`.

Comment: It's work thx for that !!!

Comment: after newMember.guild and before .createChannel can i have more precition for placement ?